# Fetch previous date with sqoop

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, hiveql, sqoop

I want to put in oozie some sqoop commands in order to be executed everyday and fetch data for previous date:

The table has a column `date_prof` and it has values like:

```
2020-09-02 05:03:02
2021-02-19 06:04:15
2021-02-10 19:05:20
etc...
```

Because its timestamp I am trying to have only the yyyy-MM-dd to get only the date, so my query inside sqoop is like:

```
select * from table date_prof like 'from_uixtime(date_sub(current_date,1),'yyyy-MM-dd')%'
```

But because of the `''` around the function it reads it as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert date_prof to date:

```
select * from table where date(date_prof) = date_sub(current_date,1)
```